# How to convert "commands module" into "subprocess module"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to know how to use "subprocess module" to rewrite the following code:

```
import commands
print commands.getoutput('convert -quality 100 ___t*.png images/transient_heat.gif')
print commands.getoutput('rm ___t*.png')
```

Because "commands module" does not support Python 3, I would like to use "subprocess module". I tried the following code but it does not work.

```
import subprocess
print ( subprocess.Popen('convert -quality 100 ___t*.png images/transient_heat.gif') )
print ( subprocess.Popen('rm ___t*.png') )
```

Thank you very much! The code was originally taken from Kitchin's blog: http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2013/03/07/Transient-heat-conduction-partial-differential-equations/

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? Edit the question.

Comment: @PeterWood I ran the code but I cannot generate the output file "images/transient_heat.gif". Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subprocess` expects a list of strings that form the command. You could split your commands up by hand like so:

```
import subprocess
print(subprocess.Popen(['convert', '-quality', '100', '___t*.png', 'images/transient_heat.gif']))
print (subprocess.Popen(['rm', '___t*.png']))
```

or, you could let `shlex.split()` do the work for you:

```
import shlex
import subprocess
print (subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('convert -quality 100 ___t*.png images/transient_heat.gif')))
print (subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('rm ___t*.png')))
```

**EDIT**:

The following code will show you the output of `stdout` and `stderr` when it executes, which may help you fix any mistakes in your command line.

```
import shlex
import subprocess

convert_proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('convert -quality 100 ___t*.png images/transient_heat.gif'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
outs, errs = convert_proc.communicate()
print('STDOUT: {}'.format(outs))
print('STDERR: {}'.format(errs))

subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('convert -quality 100 ___t*.png images/transient_heat.gif'))
print (subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('rm ___t*.png')))
```

Comment: I tried both codes but they cannot output "'images/transient_heat.gif'". Thank you!

Comment: Try using the full path to the convert utility, instead of just "convert". You can find the full path out by executing "which convert" from a shell prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)

```
print subprocess.check_output('rm ___t*.png', shell=True)
```

Comment: When I did not, it returns the error message: `CalledProcessError: Command 'convert -quality 100 ___t*.png images/transient_heat.gif' returned non-zero exit status 4`. Could you give me a help? Thank you!

Comment: @world2005 did you use `shell=True`

Comment: yes, I used `shell=True`. The codes are `subprocess.check_output(['convert', '-quality', '100', '___t*.png', 'images/transient_heat.gif'], shell=True)` and `subprocess.check_output(['rm ___t*.png'], shell=True)`. Thank you!

Comment: If you're passing a list of commands, you shouldn't use shell.  Also, each item in the list should only contain one argument -- `['rm', '___t*.png']`